# Can I annotate an inherited final property with @Autowire?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, ibatis

Resolution: No I'm no longer extending the original parent.

Original:
Is there a way to annotate an inherited `final` setter method? I am extending a class which has a `final` setter which I would like to `@Autowire` with Spring. The parent class is from a library and cannot be modified.

A workaround I have found is to write a proxy method, but this seems like more work than necessary.

```
public abstract class SqlMapClientDaoSupport ... {
    public final void setSqlMapClient(SqlMapClient smc) {
        ...
    }
}

@Component
public class AccountDao extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport {
    // all this just to annotate an existing method?
    @Autowire
    public final void setSqlMapClientWorkaround(SqlMapClient smc) {
        super.setSqlMapClient(smc);
    }
}
```

***Edit 1:*** Above example modified to reflect use case:
The use case is implementing DAO objects for Ibatis/Spring
which extend a common [base class](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/support/SqlMapClientDaoSupport.html). Each DAO needs the same
property set, and each needs to be configured as a bean. I currently
do this by configuring each individually in `applicationContext.xml`.

```
<bean id="accountDAO" 
  class="com.example.proj.dao.h2.AccountDAOImpl"
  p:sqlMapClient-ref="sqlMapClient" />
<bean id="companyDAO" 
  class="com.example.proj.dao.h2.CompanyDAOImpl"
  p:sqlMapClient-ref="sqlMapClient" />
<!-- etc... -->
```

I would prefer to use component-scan to discover and autowire the DAO
objects automatically, which I can't copy/paste botch.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.proj.dao.h2" />
```

I do not see in the [annotation guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) how one would annotate a
property/member other than where declared. I'm hoping that is
something I'm missing though.

***Edit 2:*** I am no longer extending the SqlMapClientDaoSupport class, instead my AccountDao is a POJO which implements what little functionality was being provided by the Support class. This allows me to use @Autowire at will.

Comment: What would the syntax to annotate a method on a superclass, without redeclaring it in the subclass be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to annotate an inherited final method.

Rather than extend the support class (`SqlMapClientDaoSupport`) I reimplemented it in my project (it's behavior is minimal) annotating the methods as needed, and my DAO extend that support class.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried configuring it with xml? Because it's an existing class which it looks like you can't change, it's a definite candidate for configuring it with xml. Then you can specify it as autowire", or even configure the property in the xml.

Comment: Yes, I can configure MyClass in the applicationConfig.xml. The desire
to use @Autowire is because several classes in the same package each
need the same property set. I've updated the original question

Comment: You could look at using an "abstract" bean definition. At least then you won't have to declare the property in every bean, all you'll need to do is reference that abstract bean as a parent bean. Problem with using the annotation approach is that you need access to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you shouldn't be trying to set a final field.

There is usually a good reason why fields are final.

Have you setup a SqlMapClientFactoryBean object ?

See [here for help](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-ibatis-setup)

Comment: The field is final, not to prevent setting it, but to prevent overriding it's behavior. It is my SqlMapClientFactoryBean that I was trying to get Spring to pass in using @Autowired.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new constructor with params for all the setters that are final and `@Autowired` the constructor, then call the setters in the constructor.